# How can I make my code recognize the function defined above

Tags: python, function

I am trying to run through a set of CSV files in order to compile a results CSV file.  I'm getting an error that my function is undefined for some reason. Can you tell me why?  Thanks.

```
def response_amp(data):
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#putting in and cutting out unnecessary parts of the data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
df = df[:-1]
a = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('µ')]
df = df[a]

dfd = df.drop(df.index[:30]) #dropping the section with no sample

#splitting the data into chunks so response values can be measure
df1d = dfd[:320] #first interval
df2d = dfd[330:470] #second interval
df3d = dfd[480:] #third interval

#rolling avg on each 

df1r = df1d.rolling(5, win_type='gaussian').sum(std=4)
df2r = df2d.rolling(5, win_type='gaussian').sum(std=4)
df3r = df3d.rolling(5, win_type='gaussian').sum(std=4)

bsln_1 = df1r.iloc[3:6].mean()
bsln_2 = df2r.iloc[3:6].mean()
bsln_3 = df3r.iloc[3:6].mean()
response_1 = abs(df1r.min()-bsln_1)/bsln_1
response_2 = abs(df1r.min()-bsln_2)/bsln_2
response_3 = abs(df1r.min()-bsln_3)/bsln_3

response = response_1,response_2,response_3


return(response)

import os
directory =(r'file directory goes here')
response = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
if filename.endswith(".csv"):
    response.append(response_amp(filename))

a = numpy.asarray(response)
numpy.savetxt("ks_response.csv", a, delimiter=",")
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please in the next time target your tags more specifically. Tag #function will involve half of the community here, which definitely isn't a good idea.

Comment: Have you tried properly indenting the body of the function (up though the return statement) to one level past its declaration?

Comment: There are problems in the code, check to indent, also you have declared data as the function parameter but not use it while reading the csv.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try them and let you know.